# Creating Windows Startup Services via REG or Command Line

Tags: windows, service, registry, startup, administrator

I have a Java program which needs to be a startup program that runs as administrator. It seems that cannot be done without making it a service. I have tried using `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Services\MyService`. I tried something similar to what Google Updater uses (they use `...\Services\gupdate`). The process does not start (or at least it stops right away, which I cannot tell for sure.

I think it is something wrong with how I am using the registry because the service does not show up in `msconfig.exe` under the Services tab. Also it doe not show up in the Control Panel "View local services" (Windows 7, found in the Start Menu search for "services")

I tried a [much simpler approach found here](http://www.vistax64.com/net-general/180428-creating-windows-service.html). I create a `.reg` file with these contents.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService]
"Description"="My Service starts the Special Process."

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\\Test\\MyProcess.cmd"
```

I am willing to consider an alternative command-line alternative if necessary, but I like the registry approach because if I tell my installer to add certain registry items, it will automatically remove those items on uninstall.

Is there any reason that above `.reg` file would not add an item to `msconfig` that is named "MyService"?

The program which I wrote is written in Java. It does not have a GUI interface.

Comment: it's my understanding that you are not developing this program yourself, you have an application which is not a windows service so you should not try to install it as a Service. If my assumptions are wrong please clarify editing the question. What kind of application is this (windows or console) and in which language did you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a service by manipulating the registry.  Nor can you run an arbitrary application as a service.

To run an arbitrary program from within a service, use the srvany.exe service available in the [Windows Server 2003 resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657).  See [KB137890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) for instructions.  If you want to write your own service, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

To create a service you can use the sc command line tool, or the instsrv.exe tool from the Windows Server 2003 resource kit.  Or use the CreateService Win32 API function.

Comment: Not sure if necro-ing is appreciated here (Add add a comment is still avalable), but according to [lx07](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/100592-wimlib-imagex-16299-64-16299-125-leaves-winsxs-temp-files-2.html#post1241357) on TenForums it's possible (yet the OP there doesn't seem to have managed it yet).

Comment: @script'n'code, it is perfectly normal to add a comment years afterwards, so no worries there.  Lx07 is using Windows PE, not Windows proper, and he's installing the service offline (from a different instance of Windows than the one he is manipulating) so really that's apples-and-oranges.  I don't imagine it is *impossible* to install a service this way on a running system (provided you don't mind rebooting) but it's unsupported and just not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: ... as for why it isn't working for the OP in your link, hard to say.  They might just be overlooking something, but it is also possible that they are being blocked by their anti-virus software.  For all I know, there are countermeasures built into Windows itself.

Comment: It could be a safeguard protection yes, but we'll probably never get to know the facts. I can also confirm that i'm getting the same results as the OP. With- and without anti-virus enabled, not with rebooting and also not by loading and manipulating install.wim's \Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM registry hive.

Comment: @script'n'code, it might be possible to install a service in an offline image using `dism /Add-Driver` and a suitable `.inf` file.  If you're installing Windows, I'm fairly sure it is possible to install a service during the "specialize" installation pass by using the `RunSynchronous` option in `unattend.xml`, though IIRC the last time I actually needed to do that I was still running Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

You **can** create a service by editing the registry, but (as should be apparent) you **must have a service executable associated with the service**. `Reg Add` will allow for the addition of these keys/values.

The registry must be reloaded by the system before the service is recognized, I find a reboot gets the job done.

- Add the key `ServiceName` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\`.
- Next add the following values within the `ServiceName` key:

  - `DisplayName - REG_SZ - Sample Service`
  - `Description - REG_SZ - This Service is the Hello World Service!`
  - `ErrorControl - REG_DWORD - 1 (decimal)`
  - `ImagePath - REG_EXPAND_SZ - C:\ProgramData\Program\service_executable.exe`
  - `ObjectName - REG_SZ - Username_For_Execution` (often LocalSystem)
  - `Start - REG_DWORD - 2 (decimal)` (this varies according to the desired start behavior)
  - `Type - REG_DWORD - 16 (decimal)`

The following websites were helpful in decoding the meaning of the various values:

- [Using the registry editor to change the service state](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-services-regedit.html)
- [What are the ErrorControl, Start and Type values under the Services subkeys?](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/what-are-errorcontrol-start-and-type-values-under-services-subkeys)

Just root around inside the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\` key for more examples!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a program with administrative privileges, there is another way instead of using service.

You can use Task Scheduler, [for example](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/run-a-program-with-administrative-privileges-without-uac-prompts/).

Also command line is available: SCHTASKS /create